# Atualizar a Main através de um IntentService

Tags: java, android, servidor, services, intent

Tenho uma aplicação que trabalha em conjunto ao GCM (Google Cloud Messages), que consulta o servidor e quando há novidades envia uma notificação ao usuário.

Preciso atualizar minha listView da MainActivity, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Eu devo implementar dentro do meu IntentService ou na MainActivity?

Se possível gostaria de um exemplo.

Comment: Você gostaria que todas as Notificações sejam exibidas? Pensa em salvar os dados? Ou conforme vão sendo consumindo as notificações somem?

Comment: Então Leonardo Rocha, qual situação que o @Thiago Luiz citou você gostaria?